# $f,\ g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, to prove $f-g$ is constant

Tags: general-topology

$f,\ g:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ are continuous such that $f(x)-g(x)$ is an integer for all $x \in[a,b]$. To prove $f-g$ is constant

My attempt:
Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous it implies $f-g$ is continuous
Continuous image of connected set is connected so $\{(f-g)(x)|x\in[a,b]\}$ is connected, but this is a set of integers and only connected subset of integers is singleton so $f-g$ is constant

This question is an exercise under Intermediate Value Property, so I was wondering if there is a solution using IVP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f-g$ be not constant.

Then, there exists distinct real numbers $h$ and $k$ such that $(f-g)(h) \ne (f-g)(k)$.

However, both $(f-g)(h)$ and $(f-g)(k)$ are integers.

As we know, there are non-integers between two integers. Let $d$ be such a non-integer.

By IVP, there must be another real number $c$ between $h$ and $k$ such that $(f-g)(c) = d$, contradicting the assumption that $(f-g)([a,b]) \subseteq \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please let me know if there is any mistake in my attempt.

Comment: There is no mistake in your attempt.